# How to manage frequent data access in .net application?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, asp.net-mvc, caching

I have three tables in my sql Database say **Specials**, **Businesses**, **Comments**. And in my master page i have a prompt area where i need to display alternative data from these 3 tables based on certain conditions during each page refresh (These tables have more than 1000 records). So in that case what will be the best option to retrieve data from these tables?

Accessing data each time from database is not a good idea i know, is there any other good way to do this, like Caching or any other new techniques to effectively manage this. Now it takes too much time to load the page after each page refresh.

Please give your suggestions.

At present what i was planning is to create a SP for data retrieval and to keep the value returned in a Session.

So that we can access the data from this session rather going to DB each time on page refresh. But do not know is there any other effective way to accomplish the same.

Answer (score 3):

> Accessing data each time from database is not a good idea

It not always true, it depends on how frequently the data is getting changed. If you choose to cache the data, you will have to revalidate it every time the data is changed. I am assuming you do not want to display a static count or something that once displayed will not change. If that's not the case, you can simply store in cookies and display from there.

> Now it takes too much time to load the page after each page refresh.

Do you know what takes too much time? Is it client side code or server side code (use Glimpse to know that)? If server side, is it the code that hits the DB and the query execution time or its server side in memory manipulation.

Generally first step to improve performance is to measure it precisely and in order for you to solve such issues you ought to know where the problem is.

Based on your first statement, If i were you, I would display each count in a separate div which will be refreshed asynchronously. You could choose to update the data periodically using a timer or even better push it from server (use SignalR). The update will happen transparently so no page reload required.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Actually it works like on our landing page there will be one prompt area with randomly selected three (say A,B,C) questions from these three tables. And if a user clicks on B, he will be redirected to the details page of B, same time new randomly selected A,B,C will load in that prompt area and so on. And the reason for too much time is my server side code because each table contains 1000 records. So each time to select my A,B,C i need to complete certain conditions check. That one is causing the delay

Comment: Will question changes if user refresh the page or remains same for one user after he logs in?

Comment: No the questions will change on each page refresh and its not necessary to display the up to dated data from DB on each page refresh.

Comment: Then in that case you have to hit the database to fetch randomly selected question. The db is your question bank and only it can provide questions. I would not worry about caching but check what exactly is taking time at server side. 1000 records is nothing in todays world so it must be poor implementation somewhere.

Comment: In my above comment i edited with its not necessary to display the up to dated data from DB on each page refresh. Also at server side the check is goes like this, while fetching the records each time it will have to check whether the logged in user already answered for that question or not and this same check goes with other 2 tables too. So if there is 1000 it has to check 1000 times to search for display questions. That is actually causing the issue.

Comment: I would go other way round, instead of checking whether questions are answered by the user or not, I will create a table with userId and QuestionId and this will help me fetching 1 question except already answered. Does that make sense?

Comment: That one is a good suggestion. I will check that possibility.

Comment: Thanks I am using  cookies for Delivery rate for eCommerce which is frequently accessed non sensitive information.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that 1000 records doesn't seem like a lot, but if you really aren't concerned about there being a slight delay you may try using HttpContext.Cache object.  It's very much like a dictionary with string keys and object values, with the addition that you can set expirations etc...

Excuse typos, on mobile so no compile check:

```
var tableA = HttpContext.Cache.Get("TableA")
if tableA == null {
    //if its null, there was no copy in the cache so create your
    //object using your database call
    tableA = Array, List, however you store your data
    //add the item to the cache, with an expiration of 1 minute
    HTTPContext.Cache.Insert("TableA", tableA, null, NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan(0,1,0))
}
```

Now, no matter how many requests go through, you only hit the database once a minute, or once for however long you think is reasonable considering your needs.  You can also trigger a removal of the item from cache, if some particular condition happens.

Comment: This one seems like another good option. Thanks for sharing this

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is to think of your database as a mere repository to persist state.  Your application tier could cache collections of your business objects, persist them when they change, and immediately return state to your presentation tier (the web page).

This assumes all updates to the data are coming from your page.  If the database is being populated from different places, you'll need to either tie everything into a common application tier, or poll the database to update your cache.

Comment: Thanks Ed, At present what i was planning is to create a SP for data retrieval and to keep the value returned in a Session. So that we can access the data from this session rather going to DB each time on page refresh. But do not know is there any other effective way to accomplish the same.